# remove hover upon click of list of values in dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, hover

When you hover on "Menu Item", you will see dropdown with list of values.
1) "Sub-menu Item 1" 2) "Sub-menu Item 2"

I wanted to remove the hover, when clicking on Sub-menu list. Is there any way to achieve this ?

```js
function testFunc() {
//remove hover
}
```

```css
nav ul {
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 33%;
}
nav a {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font: bold 16px/50px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav .dropdown:after {
    content: ' \25bc';
}

nav li ul {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
nav li ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="cf">
        <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Menu Item</a>
            <ul>
                <li onClick="testFunc()"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li onClick="testFunc()"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2erxyz7x/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (in Chrome and FF)

```
function testFunc() {
            var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
```

And slight change to HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul class="cf">
            <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Menu Item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li onclick="testFunc()" class="item"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
                    <li onclick="testFunc()" class="item"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here's the full code as a HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function testFunc() {
            var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        nav ul {
            background: #ddd;
            font-size: 0;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        nav li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            min-width: 33%;
        }
        nav a {
            background: #ddd;
            color: #444;
            display: block;
            font: bold 16px/50px sans-serif;
            padding: 0 25px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
                -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
                -o-transition: all .25s ease;
                    transition: all .25s ease;
        }
        nav .dropdown:after {
            content: ' \25bc';
        }

        nav li ul {
            left: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 35px;
            visibility: hidden;
            z-index: 1;
            -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
                -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
                -o-transition: all .25s ease;
                    transition: all .25s ease;
        }
        nav li:hover ul {
            opacity: 1;
            top: 50px;
            visibility: visible;
        }
        nav li ul li {
            width: 100%;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="cf">
            <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Menu Item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li onclick="testFunc()" class="item"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
                    <li onclick="testFunc()" class="item"><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <input id='test' type="text" />

</body>
```

Comment: Oddly enough, my code doesn't work as a fiddle but does work as a HTML file. I've added the full code.

Comment: Steve, you might want to remove the hover from CSS. Also its easy to do with jQuery. Have jQuery add a class on click which clicked.

Comment: @Syfer, I'm not the OP. The OP asked for a javascript solution to their hover problem and I provided on that works in a browser - just not the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery method of doing this. I have added a runnable code below so you can test it right here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( 'ul li, ul li ul' ).hover(function() {
   $( 'ul li ul' ).addClass( "hovered" );
 });
 $( 'ul li ul li' ).click(function() {
   $(this).parent('ul').toggleClass( "hovered" );
 });
});
```

```css
 nav ul {
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 33%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
nav a {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font: bold 16px/50px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav .dropdown:after {
    content: ' \25bc';
}

nav li ul {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav li ul.hovered {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
nav li ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul class="cf">
        <li><a class="dropdown">Menu Item</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is a [fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/syfer/gy3hzey7/) if you want to test in different browsers.

Hope this is what you were after.

Comment: in your code I need to explicitly click on the dropdown. But I dont need the click, when you hover on the dropdown, list should appear. And upon the click, hover should disable.

Comment: There is a hover function in jQuery. I will update my code to reflect that. Will let you know once it's done.

Comment: @learning_vba, i have updated my code to add in hover as you mentioned above. If this answers your question please select it as the correct answer. If somethings not right let me know. ps: Fiddle updated also ;-)

Comment: I tried using https://jsfiddle.net/syfer/gy3hzey7/
Hover is not working.